# Macro in Excel to Format data fields on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a Macro to parse through all the worksheets in a spreadsheet and set the data format on a report that looks like this:

[image: Report Example]

- TY / LY  FP   for Sales and Stock = Number no decimals
- FP VAR = % Value
- TY /LY FP  COVER / COVER BRN = Number 1 decimal place

Please note that when there are no data rows returned (e.g - Sales for High Tops in the example below) - the category is omitted in the cross tab.
[image: Report Example 2]

Please note, I am new to Macros in Excel - I am a BI developer and have some coding experience but not in VBA.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for telling us. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please note that this is not a free coding site.Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)